# Dynamically populate chart data from python flask application

Tags: javascript, python, flask, amcharts

I am using amCharts javascript library to put up charts on the web browser.

Following is the javascript code in HTML file:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>amCharts examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="../amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;

        var chartData = [
            {
                "year": 2003,
                "europe": 2.5,
                "namerica": 2.5,
                "asia": 2.1,
                "lamerica": 0.3,
                "meast": 0.2,
                "africa": 0.1
            },
            {
                "year": 2004,
                "europe": 2.6,
                "namerica": 2.7,
                "asia": 2.2,
                "lamerica": 0.3,
                "meast": 0.3,
                "africa": 0.1
            },
            {
                "year": 2005,
                "europe": 2.8,
                "namerica": 2.9,
                "asia": 2.4,
                "lamerica": 0.3,
                "meast": 0.3,
                "africa": 0.1
            }
        ];

        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIALL CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.categoryField = "year";
            chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0.2;
            chart.rotate = true;

            // AXES
            // Category
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

            // value
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPHS
            // firstgraph
            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Europe";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "europe";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#C72C95";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#C72C95'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // second graph
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "North America";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "namerica";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#afbb86'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // third graph
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Asia-Pacific";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "asia";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#74bdb0'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // fourth graph
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Latin America";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "lamerica";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#69A55C";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#69A55C'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // fifth graph
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Middle-East";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "meast";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#B5B8D3";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#7a81be'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // sixth graph
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.title = "Africa";
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "africa";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#F4E23B";
            graph.balloonText = "<b><span style='color:#c3b218'>[[title]]</b></span><br><span style='font-size:14px'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>";
            graph.labelPosition = "middle";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // LEGEND
            var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
            legend.position = "right";
            legend.borderAlpha = 0.3;
            legend.horizontalGap = 10;
            legend.switchType = "v";
            chart.addLegend(legend);

            chart.creditsPosition = "top-right";

            // WRITE
            chart.write("chartdiv");
        });

        // Make chart 2D/3D
        function setDepth() {
            if (document.getElementById("rb1").checked) {
                chart.depth3D = 0;
                chart.angle = 0;
            } else {
                chart.depth3D = 20;
                chart.angle = 30;
            }
            chart.validateNow();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:40px;">
        <input type="radio" checked="true" name="group" id="rb1" onclick="setDepth()">2D
        <input type="radio" name="group" id="rb2" onclick="setDepth()">3D
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the value of chartData to be populated from my Python Flask application in a fashion [similar to this](https://github.com/dfm/flask-d3-hello-world):

```
"""
This file is part of the flask+d3 Hello World project.
"""
import json
import flask
import numpy as np


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    """
    When you request the root path, you'll get the index.html template.
    """
    return flask.render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/data")
@app.route("/data/<int:ndata>")
def data(ndata=100):
    """
    On request, this returns a list of ``ndata`` randomly made data points.
    :param ndata: (optional)
        The number of data points to return.
    :returns data:
        A JSON string of ``ndata`` data points.
    """
    x = 10 * np.random.rand(ndata) - 5
    y = 0.5 * x + 0.5 * np.random.randn(ndata)
    A = 10. ** np.random.rand(ndata)
    c = np.random.rand(ndata)
    return json.dumps([{"_id": i, "x": x[i], "y": y[i], "area": A[i],
        "color": c[i]}
        for i in range(ndata)])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    port = 8000

    # Open a web browser pointing at the app.
    os.system("open http://localhost:{0}".format(port))

    # Set up the development server on port 8000.
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=port)
```

I want the data() to populate the chart data.

But what do I call in the JS in HTML file in order to catch that data. Something similar to d3.json()?

Answer (score 0):

If you are embedding the JavaScript inside the HTML of your template, the best way to do it is to calculate all the values you need within Flask, and then pass them to the template.

I don't know your app logic either your database, so I just copying some values from your code above. Anyway files should look something like this:

```py
@app.route("/data")
def data():

    # sample data
    chart_data = [
        {
            "year": 2003,
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5,
            "asia": 2.1,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.2,
            "africa": 0.1
        },
        {
            "year": 2003,
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5,
            "asia": 2.1,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.2,
            "africa": 0.1
        }]

    # pass the data do the template
    return render_template('chart.html', chart_data=chart_data)
```

And your template iterate with this list inside the JavaScript block:

```
...
var chartData = [
{{ for chart in chart_data }}
    {
        "year": {{ chart.year }},
        "europe": {{ chart.europe }},
        "namerica": {{ chart.namerica }},
        "asia": {{ chart.asia }},
        "lamerica": {{ chart.lamerica }},
        "meast": {{ chart.meast }},
        "africa": {{ chart.africa }}
    }
    {{ if not loop.last }} , {{ endif }}
{{ endfor }}
]

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // SERIALL CHART
    ...
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `var chartData = {{ chart_data|tojson|safe }};`